# Method for convert generic list to another generic list

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I have Data In `List<One>` and want to convert into `List<Two>`.
my code is as

```
 public static List<T> ListCopy<T>(List<T> input)
    {
        List<T> mylist = new List<T>();
        //Logic Goes here 
        return mylist;
    }
```

this only Process data from `List<One>` to `List<One>`
but i want to process from `List<One>` to `List<Two>`  like

```
    List<One> l = new List<One>();
    List<Two> t = new List<Two>();
    t = ListConvert<Two>(l);
```

what can i do for this?

Comment: Does `Two` inherit `One`?

Comment: Assuming both are compatible types have you tried the Linq extension method `.Cast<T>()?` - you can just `ToList` the enumerable it returns

Comment: @Trickery  Plz check question once again

Comment: @Charleh  Plz check question once again

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using LINQ, but you still need to provide a function that should be used to convert elements:

```
public static List<TResult> ListCopy<TSource, TResult>(List<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TResult> convertFunction)
{
    return input.Select(x => convertFunction(x)).ToList();
}
```

And sample usage (with simple casting as conversion function)

```
var t = ListConvert(l, x => (Two)x);
```

Comment: i think your answer is nearly answer my question. @MarcinJuraszek thank you

Comment: i think your answer is nearly answer my question here but  `Func<TSource, TResult> convertFunction` how to use . @MarcinJuraszek thank you

Comment: Just create a method that returns `TResult` and has a single argument of type `TSource` - e.g. `private Two YourConvertMethod(One source) { return convertedItemAfterYourLogicHasRun; }` then use `var myConvertedList = myList.ListCopy(YourConvertMethod)`

Comment: Ah that use case is neat, I like how the syntactic sugar really hides the way the cast is wrapped in an anonymous so you don't need to write a function body - terse and easier to read!